# Doctrine 2 "demo" data - filling tables with development data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, demo

What is the best way to manage demo (development) data in application which uses Doctrine 2 ORM?

When I didn't use this ORM I simply draw diagram in MySQL Workbench and I used the "inserts" tab of each table to populate it with data. In Doctrine 2 I don't see such an option but I of course need it.

So, please, what is the best way to achieve that? What is your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to hear about [Doctrine Data Fixtures](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures) and [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) :-)

Comment: Thank you :) Faker looks really interesting!

Answer (score 2):

You want to hear about [Doctrine Fixtures](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures).